# ListView preview in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-studio

EDIT : this issue now only happens when I try to have a listview with a preview layout that contains databinding (from android databinding)

In android Studio, when I try to add an item preview for a listview, nothing happens (the default preview is still displayed) and in the splitted version (text + preview) I have a black screen for the preview.
First I was thinking that my layout was somehow too complex, so I tried with a simple layout file, containing only a LinearLayout and a listview. I checked that the listview has an id (and all the solutions I found on stackoverflow) but nothing works. Here is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_chat"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the screenshot of the result (the preview is supposed to be on the right). I really need to make this work, and the fact is that the same thing happen whenever I try to use tools:something.
[image]

I'm using Android Studio 1.4
Edit : I tried to clone a project that where using tools AND data binding, and the preview works!

Comment: What happens if you preview it with a different version number? Instead of 23, maybe try 21? Or whichever you have?

Comment: have you tried to re-render the layout with the reload button? And does it work with the stable builds of android studio?

Comment: The version number doesn't fix this, I will try the stable version of studio (I was sure something like this could not disappear in beta, maybe I was wrong)

Comment: Still the same with android studio 1.3.1 :(

Comment: "I really need to make this work" just out of curiosity. Why do you need to make this work? As long as it works correctly on the device,this preview is nothing more than a small hint for the developer (that's you) and how it will look at the end. But as long as it's properly shown on the device, why do you need this to work?

Comment: Yes, good question, this is because I'm using android data binding (the new feature), and (except if you have another solution) when you bind a textview  using text="@{user.name}", the preview doesn't show any text. so I would like to set something like : tools:text="My name". This is for the "absolutly needed part", but I would like to have it at least working for simple list views (no databinding if impossible) just to be able to work correctly with my designer (and not compiling each time I want to show him the layout)

Comment: hey, just try to change device frm nexus 5 to nexus 4 and change the android version from 23 to 21,  remove your xmlns:tools line from xml.

Comment: Well, it displays the layout (and I don't need to change api version or device to do this), but the preview of the list is the default one, not the one I need :(

Answer (score 2):

Hello I had checked again the UI is rendring atleast for one item. In my it is giving "Rendering Problems onLayout error" while rendering but shows one row item. To make it possible you have to make few changes in xml code:

```
    <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_chat"/>
```

make sure you are using latest build version tools. I have checked with following:

```
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1"
```

If it still gives try with latest build tools from SDK manager. I have install following plugin in addition:

Android SDK platform-tools version 23.1 rc1 under Tools(Preview channel)

[image]

Comment: Do your items contain data binding??

Comment: yes you were right there is some issue while rendring data binding view. let me check i will update you.

Comment: Ok thank you! I hope there is a way to solve this, even with a workaround

Comment: I have update answer check with new changes.
if you want to check with text also you can give text value in xml instead of using databinding value. then replace it for runtime use.

Comment: Yes, I think I will do that, hoping it will work without workarounds in the next studio/buildtools release (it doesn't work for me, I don't have anything displayed, one item would have been great). Thank you by the way! I award you for your patience :)